# How to add custom form validation in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add custom validation in my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Redirect;
use Response;
use Validator;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $req)
    {

        $v = Validator::make($req->all(), [
          'contract_ref' => 'required'
        ]);

        $v->after(function($v) use(&$req){
            dd('custom validations');

            // list of custom validations
            if ($req->div_id == '') {
                $validator->errors()->add('div_id', 'Please select a Division');
            };
        });

        dd('NO!');

        if ($v->fails()) {
         //
        }

        $v->validate();
    }

}
```

However, for some reason I don't understand. Nothing in the `-after` closure is being done. In example above, I get `"NO!"` dumped instead of the expected `"custom validations"`

This `->after` has worked for me previously and I don't get why it is not working here.

Comment: try php artisan optimize:clear.at first attempt even for me also same think happened but after running optimize command then it started working

Comment: @JohnLobo no change.

Comment: which version of Laravel (though it should make much a difference)?

Comment: @happymacarts 8.4

Comment: I have never used the after hook, does it trigger once the validator has finished pass or fail? If everything passes does it still trigger?

Comment: @happymacarts no it triggers as you would expect. How else can I add a custom validation? it is really frustrating lol!

Comment: are the items in your $req ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247291/discussion-between-happymacarts-and-matt).

Comment: it doesn't do the validation until `fails` (which calls `passes`) is called here, so the `after` closure wouldn't be called before your `dd` as validation hasn't happened yet

Comment: on a side note: it is `__construct` not `__contruct` but you don't need to define a blank constructor

Comment: @lagbox My ignorance on this part is the entire problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are requesting `dd('NO!')` before the actual validate

try this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Redirect;
use Response;
use Validator;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function __contruct()
    {
    }

    public function store(Request $req)
    {

        $v = Validator::make($req->all(), [
            'contract_ref' => 'required'
        ]);

        $v->after(function ($v) use (&$req) {
            dd('custom validations');

            // list of custom validations
            if ($req->div_id == '') {
                $validator->errors()->add('div_id', 'Please select a Division');
            };
        });


        if ($v->fails()) {
            //
        }

        $v->validate();
        dd('NO!');
    }
}
```

Comment: doh! Worst of all @happymarts actually asked if this was the problem but I thought it wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend using Closures https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures as it can keep all of your validation logic in one place

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'title' => [
    'required',
    'max:255',
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if ($value === 'foo') {
            $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
        }
    },
  ],
]);
```

Comment: This was a useful solution but did not answer the question as posted. It turns out I was wrong in my response to you regarding when the `after` gets called and that as indeed the problem. Someone else posted it as an answer so I am going to accept that one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used that?

```
$v->validate();
```

Below is an example of validation. You can also check your invalid input values inside fail check.

```
        $validation_array = [
            'id' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required|date',
            'material_type' => 'required',
            'fabric' => 'required_if:material_type,==,0',
            'color' => 'required_if:material_type,==,1',
            'quantity' => 'required|numeric',
            'unit' => 'required',
        ];

        $validation_messages_array = [
            'fabric.required'    => 'The fabric field is required when material type is fabric.',
            'color.required_if' => 'The color field is required when material type is blind.'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            $validation_array,
            $validation_messages_array
        );

        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        });

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            //code if not valid
        }

        $validator->validate();
```

Comment: that makes no difference. Remember my point is that the code before inside of the `after` is not being used for some reason. The initial validation rules are there... but just nothing from the `after`

Comment: Can you share those rules?

Comment: I have added rules above, but it doesn't matter what rules are in there, or if there are actually rules or not. No matter what I try, I can't get the `after` to fire.

Comment: Well, actually, we also need to see your class (including inherited class, validation trait) in which you use validation

Comment: now I am lost as to what you need to see. Should the code that I have not  above not work by itself? All I have is `use Validator`. Why would I need anything else to stop that block of code from being ignored?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out if your class implementation is correct. It should be using a trait for validation. Maybe something's wrong out of your code block.

Comment: sorry, wan not trying to be awkward. There isn't much else. I have added the code outside above.

Comment: Does your Controller class use a trait called ValidatesRequests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247292/discussion-between-matt-and-ahmet-firat-keler).